# Preventing overplotting for specific data points in ggplot2 scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics, scatter-plot

I am trying find a way to prevent points in my `ggplot2` scatterplot from overlapping whilst ideally not changing the position of the non-overlapping points (in this example, not moving points with the ids 1, 4, or 5).  I would like to maintain the relative position of each of the points, but they can be moved slightly in the x and y as necessary.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:9,
  x = c(1, 2, 2.1, 4, 5, 8.7, 9.1, 9, 8.9),
  y = c(10, 9, 9, 7, 6, 2.4, 2, 2.1, 2),
  size = rep(1:4, length.out = 9)
)

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = size), alpha = 0.8, shape = 21, color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = id, size = 0.4*size), color = "black") +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 8) +
  xlim(1, 10) +
  ylim(1, 10) +
  theme_bw()

plot
```

[Idea of ideal Scatterplot without overlapping points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QipDY.png)

I have tried `position_jitter` but to prevent overlap, I had to jitter all of the points so much that their relative positions were unrecognizable.  I have also attempted `position_dodge`, however, as some points need to be moved in the x and some in the y to prevent overlap, I'd basically be doing this manually for 100 data points in my original dataset. I think something similar to the way `geom_text_repel` and `geom_label_repel` moves labels the minimum amount so they don't overlap would be ideal!  Side note: this is my first post to stack overflow, apologies for any errors!!

Comment: Can you say more about your requirement? You really want to plot 100 points with different size and labels inside each of them? How about moving labels outside and using colour and opacity to show overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

The base plot function of R can utilize a jitter function as well which may suit your needs. Otherwise, I would recommend changing the transparency of your points in ggplot by adding

```
geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
```

Additionally, you could try changing the size of the points,

```
geom_point(size=1.5)
```

You could also try changing the color or shape of the points, but you would need another variable to determine what colors or shapes the points would be.